# How to Use PATINDEX or LIKE to Include Wildcards OR Beginning/End of Line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid performing a case statement or having an additional WHERE criteria when isolating a specific pattern, say " **[A-Z][A-Z]** " which can be located either at the start of, middle of, or end of a varchar field.

It seems as though you should be able to place the wildcard (%) inside a bracket to create additional criteria?

### The Question:

Does anyone have an efficient/clean solution for how to get PATINDEX/LIKE to include both the wildcard symbol AND the beginning/end of a line in it's results?

### My specific example

In my specific instance I have a set of messy city/state/zip address information.  I'm writing a query to pull out just the state abbreviations.  My attempts have been successful except in instances where the city or zip code are missing because of the wildcards in my PATINDEX.

```
with cte as 
(
select 1 as ID,'Town, FL 00012' as Address1 union
select 2      ,'Town GA, 00024'             union
select 3      ,'TX 00048'                   union
select 4      ,'Town, CA'
)
select SUBSTRING(address1,nullif(1+PATINDEX('%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%',address1),1),2) as State_Abbrev
      ,case when Address1 like '[A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%' and Address1 not like '%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%' then SUBSTRING(address1,         PATINDEX('[A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%',address1),2)
            when Address1 like '%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z]' and Address1 not like '%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%' then SUBSTRING(address1,nullif(1+PATINDEX('%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z]',address1),1),2)
            else SUBSTRING(address1,nullif(1+PATINDEX('%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%',address1),1),2)
        end as State_Complex
      ,ID,Address1
  from cte
```

Which my State_Abbrev alias returns...

> FL
>
> GA
>
> NULL
>
> NULL

and my State_Complex returns...

> FL
>
> GA
>
> TX
>
> CA

You can see my criteria works for the top two records but I have no way to isolate for the bottom two without creating the ridiculous case statement as you see in my State_Complex field.

As an aside, yes I'm aware my substring doesn't take into account all possible scenarios (like if the string accidentally has a street address like RD or LN in it) but I understand this.

Comment: I hope this is so you can clean up this mess and get your data into a properly normalized table structure. There is not much you can do when a given data element moves around in the column like this. You are likely going to need several passes at this to get all the data.

Comment: Oh believe me, I know.  I'm a data conversion specialist at my company so we deal with this crap all the time while converting legacy systems into our data structure.  Just checking on default functionality to see if this is even possible using PATINDEX/LIKE.

Edit: Oh and yes, it is to get it into proper differentiated columns instead of free-form silliness.

Comment: My best guess is you will need to make a couple passes at this to get all the permutations. Presumably you are loading this from the free-form silliness into a staging table. Shouldn't be too bad from there. The first query you have works for some it, just run that and dump the rows from your staging table it converted. Then create code for the second, third, etc passes. You could probably get something that would work but you would probably spend more time building it then just doing it in multiple passes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggstions Sean, and that's my current operating procedure in regards to most of my conversion process.  My curiosity about the LIKE wildcard criteria still remains though and I'd like further answers about that specific part if anyone else has insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose `address1` in spaces or commas. If you do so only for `PATINDEX`, additionally correct two more bits, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38867):

```
SUBSTRING(address1,nullif(0+PATINDEX('%[ ,][A-Z][A-Z][ ,]%',' '+address1+' '),0),2)
--                        ^                                 ^^^^        ^^^^  ^
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  I didn't think of modifying the source to include the characters I'm looking for to essentially turn the beginning/endline into part of the LIKE criteria.  Clever...

Answer (score 0):

Could I lead you down an alternate path?
What if you parsed the data into new rows where there is a space delimiter? And replace ,'s with ''
. Then you could look row by row.
So take Jeff Modens  Delimited split http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ function and pipe out to a new table with a Key and each value to a new row, then search out from there. You could even remove spaces ... and do a join to a StateAbbreviation table at that point.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have a working solution for resolving my data problems so that's all set.  The root question however is merely about LIKE and PATINDEX functionality and whether it's possible to combine my case statement into a single command to cut down on code.  I guess I should have put less emphasis on the data in my question and more on the LIKE wildcard functionality problem.